# Javascript output returns character twice

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have a javascript issue. I written a code that will return a string or a sentence.

to give you a better idea, here's my code:

**Javascript Code**

```
var hodor;
var eventypleselector = "HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>FORM>TEXTAREA";

var ixo = "Hello World!";
hodor ="CODE:";
hodor +="EVENT TYPE=MOUSEDOWN SELECTOR=" + eventypleselector + " BUTTON=0"+"\n";
hodor +="EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR=\"HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>FORM>TEXTAREA\" CHARS=" + "\""+ixo+"\"+n";
```

then after running the  js code in imacros, the output will like this.

**Output**

*HHeelllloo WWoorrlldd!!!!*

I'm not sure why or what's happening but it keeps on doing that. The letters from the output is shown twice. It's as if the person type in the same letter/character.

Anyone who can help out?

Comment: What is `output`? Which variable? `ixo`?

Comment: the variable ixo = "Hello World!", then if i run the code, it will return HHeelllloo WWoorrlldd!!!!

Comment: Hi, your code seems incomplete, what is the value of "eventypleselector" ?

Comment: Sorry bout that @vanessa, code added.

Comment: i don't see how this is a javascript issue

Comment: @Cruiser, thanks. I tried alert(ixo); and it works perfectly fine. no duplicate letters. hmmm. what seems to be wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Does the following iim-macro work as needed?

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>FORM>TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV:nth-of-type(4)>DIV>DIV>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>ARTICLE>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>SECTION:nth-of-type(3)>FORM>TEXTAREA" CHARS="Hello World!"
```